# How many ways can 6 boys and 4 girls stand in a row if the girls must not be together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can 6 boys and 4 girls stand in a row if the girls must not be together?

1. Arrange all 6 boys in a row . --> ways to do this is 6!
2. This leaves 7 gap in between the boys to place 4 girls in. -> $_7C_4$
3. The girls in between the boys can have 4! ways to arrange them.

therefore, answer is $6! \cdot  _7C_4 \cdot 4! $

why am i wrong ?

the right answer is $6! \cdot  _7C_4 \cdot 4! + 6! \cdot  _7C_2 \cdot 4! + 6! \cdot  _7C_2 \cdot 4!$

Comment: Maybe the boys (and girls) are not supposed to be distinguishable from eah other? What were you told the right answer is?

Comment: It looks like "girls must not be together" is supposed to mean that you can't have all four girls together rather than the stronger restriction of no two girls together. Poorly worded question.

Comment: @Ned so how does that explain the other 2 sets which are added to the working i have ?

Comment: @Erikien Looking more carefully, the only reasonable condition I can think of, with that answer, is "The girls must be in odd-size clumps, i.e. 1 or 3". The first term are the ones you counted, next term counts orders where girls are 3,1 left-to-right, and last term counts orders with girls 1,3 left to right. There may be something more natural, but that's all I can think of, assuming the answer is correct to whatever the intended question is.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have girls $A,B,C,D$. The numbers that $X,Y$ are together is $2\cdot 9!$, then $X,Y$ and $Y,Z$ are together is $2\cdot 8!$. Now we use PIE.

Then at least two are together is $${4\choose 2}\cdot 2\cdot 9!-24\cdot 8! = 84\cdot 8!$$

So the answer is $$10!-84\cdot 8! = 8! (90-84) = 6\cdot 8!$$